# www-data default permissions on files/directories

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a very interesting situation.  I have a Debian Lenny server running Apache/2.2.9 and PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny10.  When Apache creates a new file (simple php upload script or http svn checkin) the permissions and ownership on the file is:

```
www-data test -rwxr-xr-x
```

When a new directory is created the permissions and ownership are:

```
www-data    test drwxr-sr-x
```

I have made changes on the server to `/etc/profile` with `umask 0002`.  This setting is supposed to make newly created files to 664 and newly created directories to 775.  It ONLY does this when I actually log in as the `www-data` user and manually do so via command line.  It does NOT do it when Apache creates the data.  Has anyone else ever witnessed this behavior?  What is the difference between logging in as the "www-data" user and creating files versus the "www-data" user running through Apache?  Do the files inherit permissions from the `/tmp` folder or something?  I'm interested in directly resolving the default permissions with Apache not implementing a workaround.

Here are my steps thus far:

1. create a new group (test)
2. usermod -a -G test usera
3. usermod -a -G test userb
4. groups usera
5. Change the ownership of everything under html/ with the user and new group
6. chmod 2775 html/
7. find html/ -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
8. find html/ -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
9. edit /etc/profile with new umask setting of 0002
10. restarted apache and logged in and out with the "www-data" user and site user

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user mentions how to set the umask for apache on debian.

/etc/profile is only loaded by interactive shells.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I'll give that a try and report back.